# Merge two lists of classes implementing the same interface

Tags: c#, list, interface

In a class, I process a list of `IInterface`.

I want the two possible implementations to be treated in a separate way, hence:

```
public List<IInterface> Process(List<IInterface> InterfaceList)
{
    List<FirstImplementation> FirstList = FirstProcess(InterfaceList.OfType<FirstImplementation>.ToList());

    List<SecondImplementation> SecondList = SecondProcess(InterfaceList.OfType<SecondImplementation>.ToList());

   return new List<IInterface> {
    FirstList,
    SecondList
};

}
```

I would like to return a `List<IInterface>`, same as the input, both it turns out to be more difficult than anticipated

```
   return new List<IInterface> {
    FirstList,
    SecondList
};
```

compiles but throws an InvalidCastException at runtime,

```
return new List<IInterface>.AddRange(FirstList).AddRange(SecondList);
```

does not even compile...

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Your last example is almost correct. It's missing parenthesis and `AddRange` has return type `void` so you cannot chain it together: `var ret = new List<IInterface>(); ret.AddRange(FirstList); ret.AddRange(SecondList); return ret;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
return FirstList.Cast<IInterface>().Concat(SecondList.Cast<IInterface>()).ToList();
```

`Cast<>` returns an enumerable (mind linq's deferred execution) with elements cast to the target type, `Concat` combines two enumerables and `ToList` turns the result into a list (and materializes the linq query).

As @Evk kindly noticed, when there is an implicit cast from both types to the output type (as in your case, you can cast both your types to their common interface), you can skip the cast completely (though in that case you need to explicitly specify the type for concatenation), as follows:

```
return FirstList.Concat<IInterface>(SecondList).ToList();
```

Comment: You don't even need the `.Cast<IInterface>` the second time.

Comment: You don't need Cast at all, you can just do `FirstList.Concat<IInterface>(SecondList).ToList();`

Comment: Correct, I was writing this for a more generic example, where there was no implicit cast.